# Equivalent of Platform::IBoxArray in C++/WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I am currently porting an UWP application from C++/CX to C++/WinRT. I encountered a `safe_cast<Platform::IBoxArray<byte>^>(data)` where `data` is of type `Windows::Foundation::IInspectable ^`.

I know that the `safe_cast` is represented by the `as<T>` method, and I know there are functions for boxing (`winrt::box_value`) and unboxing (`winrt::unbox_value`) in WinRT/C++.

However, I need to know the equivalent of `Platform::IBoxArray` in order to perform the cast (QueryInterface). According to https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/cppcx/platform-iboxarray-interface?view=vs-2017, `IBoxArray` is the C++/CX equivalent of `Windows::Foundation::IReferenceArray`, but there is no `winrt::Windows::Foundation::IReferenceArray`...

**Update for nackground:** What I am trying to achieve is retrieving the view transform attached by the HoloLens to every Media Foundation sample from its camera. My code is based on https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloLensForCV, and I got really everything working except for this last step. The problem is located around this piece of code:

```
static const GUID MF_EXTENSION_VIEW_TRANSFORM = {
    0x4e251fa4, 0x830f, 0x4770, 0x85, 0x9a, 0x4b, 0x8d, 0x99, 0xaa, 0x80, 0x9b
};

// ...

// In the event handler, which receives const winrt::Windows::Media::Capture::Frames::MediaFrameReader& sender:

auto frame = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame();
// ...

if (frame.Properties().HasKey(MF_EXTENSION_VIEW_TRANSFORM)) {
    auto /* IInspectable */ userData = frame.Properties().Lookup(MF_EXTENSION_VIEW_TRANSFORM);

    // Now I would have to do the following:
    // auto userBytes = safe_cast<Platform::IBoxArray<Byte> ^>(userData)->Value;
    //viewTransform = *reinterpret_cast<float4x4 *>(userBytes.Data);
}
```

Comment: What API are you trying to use?

Comment: I am trying to extract the HoloLens view transform from a Media Foundation sample - this code uses a self-defined GUID that I got from Microsofts C++/CX sample to obtain the `IInspectable`, which is then casted to `IBoxArray` and then reinterpret_casted to a float4x4 Matrix. So the problem is: I need to know the interface for the first cast, but I found no way to obtain this from the debugger or so ...

Comment: I'm not familiar with that API but you might want to try `Windows::Foundation::IReferenceArray<T>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also working on porting some code from HoloLensForCV to C++/WinRT. I came up with the following solution for a very similar case (but not the exact same line of code you ask about):

```
auto user_data = source.Info().Properties().Lookup(c_MF_MT_USER_DATA); // type documented as 'array of bytes'
auto source_name = user_data.as<Windows::Foundation::IReferenceArray<std::uint8_t>>(); // Trial and error to get the right specialization of IReferenceArray
winrt::com_array<std::uint8_t> arr;
source_name.GetUInt8Array(arr);
winrt::hstring source_name_str{ reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(arr.data()) };
```

Specifically, you can replace the `safe_cast` with `.as<Windows::Foundation::IReferenceArray<std::uint8_t>` for a boxed array of bytes. Then, I suspect doing the same cast as me (except to float4x4* instead of wchar_t*) will work for you.

The /ZW flag is not required for my example above.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Can’t believe this doesn’t seem to be documented anywhere. For other kinds of arrays (e.g. `String[]`) check the list of methods on `IReferenceArray`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.ireferencearray-1?view=winrt-22000#methods

Comment: I eventually found the time to test this while porting my code to HoloLens 2. That was exactly what I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe that actually worked, but using information from https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/interop-winrt-cx, I came up with the following solution:

Enable "Consume Windows Runtime Extension" via /ZW and use the following conversion:

```
auto abi = reinterpret_cast<Platform::Object ^>(winrt::get_abi(userData));
auto userBytes = safe_cast<Platform::IBoxArray<byte> ^>(abi)->Value;
viewTransform = *reinterpret_cast<float4x4 *>(userBytes->Data);
```

Unfortunately, the solution has the drawback of generating

> warning C4447: 'main' signature found without threading model. Consider using 'int main(Platform::Array^ args)'.

But for now, I can live with it ...