# How to unbox multivalue string in c++ winrt

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

I can look for services on the network using

```cpp
std::vector<hstring> propertyKeys = std::vector<hstring>();
propertyKeys.push_back(L"System.Devices.Dnssd.HostName");
propertyKeys.push_back(L"System.Devices.IpAddress");

hstring aqsQueryString = L"System.Devices.AepService.ProtocolId:={4526e8c1-8aac-4153-9b16-55e86ada0e54} AND System.Devices.Dnssd.ServiceName:=\"_http._tcp\" AND System.Devices.Dnssd.Domain:=\"local\"";

auto watcher = DeviceInformation::CreateWatcher(aqsQueryString, propertyKeys, DeviceInformationKind::AssociationEndpointService);
```

I then set the `Updated` callback to get information about services.

```cpp
watcher.Updated([](DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformationUpdate info) {
    for(auto const& p : info.Properties()){
        hstring s = unbox_value_or<hstring>(p.Value(), L""); // This unboxes the Hostname
        auto ips = unbox_value_or<???>(p.Value(), ???); // How do I unbox this?
    }
}
```

According to [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-devices-ipaddress) the `System.Devices.IpAddress` is of type `Multivalue String`. I've tried with `std::vector<hstring>` but that doesn't work as the type must be a winrt type.

What type do I put to unbox a multivalue string?

Comment: MS documentation has really gone downhill for their newer projects, hasn't it? Best I can find is a C# example, where this property is a `string[]`. https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-appsample-networkhelper/blob/master/NetworkHelper/DnssdParticipant.cs . Other winrt collection types I can find are `array_view` and `IVector`, any of those work?

Comment: `winrt::array_view<winrt::hstring>` complains that it is not a winrt type (?) and `unbox_value<Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<winrt::hstring>>` throws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it using Sean Kellys answer from here: [Equivalent of Platform::IBoxArray in C++/WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948092/equivalent-of-platformiboxarray-in-c-winrt)

Specifically my implementation for printing the first IP looks like this:

```cpp
auto prop = info.Properties();
auto ips = prop.Lookup(L"System.Devices.IpAddress").as<Windows::Foundation::IReferenceArray<hstring>>();
winrt::com_array<hstring> arr;
ips.GetStringArray(arr);
std::wcout << arr[0].c_str() << std::endl;
```